# Streaming android screen using Webrtc + python

Tags: python, android, aiortc

I'm trying to stream android screen using python + aiortc. 
I have a POC to obtain the device screen using adb + screenrecord. The provided code reads the raw output (h264) from the execution of screenrecord and shows it using ffmpeg and opencv.

```
import subprocess as sp
import cv2
import array
import numpy as np

adbCmd = ['adb', 'exec-out', 'screenrecord', '--output-format=h264', '-']
stream = sp.Popen(adbCmd, stdout= sp.PIPE, universal_newlines = True)

ffmpegCmd = ['ffmpeg', '-i', '-', '-f', 'rawvideo', '-vcodec', 'bmp', '-vf', 'fps=5', '-']
ffmpeg = sp.Popen(ffmpegCmd, stdin=stream.stdout, stdout=sp.PIPE)

while True:
    fileSizeBytes = ffmpeg.stdout.read(6)
    fileSize = 0
    for i in range(4):
        fileSize += fileSizeBytes[i + 2] * 256 ** i
    bmpData = fileSizeBytes + ffmpeg.stdout.read(fileSize - 6)
    image = cv2.imdecode(np.fromstring(bmpData, dtype=np.uint8), 1)
    cv2.imshow("im", image)
    cv2.waitKey(25)
```

Currently, I'm trying to plug the output from ffmpeg or adb exec-out to an aiortc media streamer. Based on [this](https://github.com/aiortc/aiortc/blob/master/examples/server/server.py) example I replaced the recv method with the fallowing code

```
async def recv(self):
    fileSizeBytes = ffmpeg.stdout.read(6)
    fileSize = 0
    for i in range(4):
        fileSize += fileSizeBytes[i + 2] * 256 ** i
    bmpData = fileSizeBytes + ffmpeg.stdout.read(fileSize - 6)
    image = cv2.imdecode(numpy.fromstring(bmpData, dtype=numpy.uint8), 1)

    frame = VideoFrame.from_ndarray(
        image, format="bgr24"
    )

    pts, time_base = await self.next_timestamp()
    frame.pts = pts
    frame.time_base = time_base
    self.counter += 1
    return frame
```

But this code is not able to stream the correct video from device screen and no error happen. I'm looking for solutions for this problem. I was thinking to use the direct output from adbCmd but it also didn't worked.

Comment: I would really like to know this answer too!

Comment: Hy i am working on a similar thing. (i want to feed the screen from my phone to tensorflow model) the ADB Command outputs data. But ffmpeg doesn't give any thing except empty byte strings?